# Sharing mode in CSV Data Set Config in Http Request

Tags: jmeter

In a Http Request, how the values from the CSV file can be shared.

In the Https request I have a variable in 100 places but wanted the different values from CSV to distribute among 100 places having one variable name in the same http request of the thread group.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using CSV Data Set Config as it will update the variable value either for each virtual user or for each iteration.

You can consider [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) as an alternative, it is pretty easy:

- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,0)}` reads 1st column from `test.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,1)}` - reads 2nd column
- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,2)}` - reads 3rd column
- etc.
- `${__CSVRead(test.csv,next)}` - goes to the next line

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime)